# Trouble with clicking after layout animation

Tags: android, layout

I have a ListView on screen and a menu at the bottom. Upon a click of menu key, it animates-slides off the screen and the ListView expands.

```
        menuBtmVisable = false;
        Animation menu_off = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.menu_off);
        menubtm.startAnimation(menu_off);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        LayoutParams listlp = new LayoutParams(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight()-87 , 0, 50);
        ListViewMain.setLayoutParams(listlp);
```

menu_off.xml

```
 <set
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="120"
        android:duration="500"
     />
</set>
```

Yet when, with the menu down, I click on the ListView item "13" ( see picture ), it results in a menu click, as if it is still in place...

What do you think would be the best way to take care of it?

Comment: picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4DbpA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've looking for an answer for a problem like that, and finally, after a week, I've managed to solve my problem. Since it looks similar to yours, maybe it will help you.

Set up and `AnimationListener()` in your animation and, `onAnimationEnd`, change the layout as you want. In my case, I wanted to slide a layout up, so 2 buttons would appear from below. However, the layout just slided visually; the buttons would still be off screen, interactionally speaking. So I have something like this:

```
final View screen = findViewById(R.id.welcome_screen);
final Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_home_up);
a.setFillAfter(true);
a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        screen.clearAnimation();
        screen.setPadding(0, -222, 0, 0);
    }
});
screen.startAnimation(a);
```